# Exclude certain similarly named Apex Classes in source retrieval with Package.XML in VSC

Tags: apex, package.xml, visualstudiocode

Wondering if anyone has experience tweaking the manifest XML file to disclude certain Apex Classes being pulled into Visual Studio Code. I know you can use the * as a wildcard to include certain groups of similarly named apex classes but i want to disclude groups of similarly named apex classes. Does anyone know the syntax to do so? These apex classes i want to disclude are all from apps downloaded from the app exchange (managed packages)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think what you want to achieve is possible simply using a wildcard pattern in a package.xml.

From my understanding the package.xml only has two ways of formulating inclusion: either a wildcard  *for metadata types that support the wildcard - which then includes all instances of that metadata type (some special cases excluded like*  for type CustomObject does really get all custom object but none of the standard objects) or list each instance of a metadata type individually.
This behaviour is also true for ApexClasses.
Similarly the command line options of sfdx force:source:retrieve also allow you to retrieve all instances of a metadata type, e.g. `sfdx force:source:retrieve -m ApexClass` would retrieve all ApexClasses or the explicitly listed instances of a metadata type.

Neither the package.xml nor the commandline options of sfdx allow to exclude instances of metadata types, a wildcard really means all (well, special cases not considered) and can not be used to build a pattern of names to include (i.e. *Controller of type ApexClass).